# Listen for a new message to alert all my IOS & Android apps, when app is running in foreground

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin

My IOS and Android app connect to a 3rd party server, in case there an issue with the server, I would like the option to let the users know of the issue, when they open the app, or an alert would popup a dialog within the app, that they click OK to. In a way I want my app to goto a "server" and see if a new message is there, to present to the user.
Thanks for any suggestions

Have looked at push notifications, which pop alerts to the phone, but only really after a method for checking for a message once app is running.
I think I'm after a check for new messages method.

Comment: That's not what push messages do.  Push messages send a data blob to your phone.  You can then do whatever you want in response to them-  show a notification, write to a db, or anything else.  They are 100% the answer to your problem.  The alternative is polling the server, which is generally wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this problem. You can use Firebase Cloud Function and Realtime database together to listen to changes.

`addValueEventListener()` is the method provided by Firebase RTDB where you can write your logic to execute. The Firebase cloud function will be used to update the real-time database and app(s) will be listening to the changes in the database.

Comment: I have no experience of Firebase, but will look at that avenue.

Comment: Firebase services are widely used by mobile apps. I will recommend to give it a try once.